# How to use expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable on a WebElement? "argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement"

Tags: python, selenium

I'm needing to add a new condition to the code below because my click and arrow_right commands have sometimes been (unknowingly) failing:

```
        value_items = \
            (selection_section.find_elements_by_class_name("stuff") +
             selection_section.find_elements_by_class_name("stuff1")) or \
            (selection_section.find_elements_by_css_selector(".stuff2.stuff3"))


        for value in value_items:
            if value.text in values_to_select:
                self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", value)

                # Removing "move_to_element" from the ActionChains below seems to result in a marginal speed-up, but often causes the run
                # to fail when running headless. (The run can also fail with "move_to_element", just not as often)
                
                self.wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(value))

                ActionChains(self.browser).click(value).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform()
```

The documentation for [element_to_be_clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) states that it accepts either a locator or a WebElement, but when I run the code above I get the following error:

```
TypeError: selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong

You use `element_to_be_clickable` too later (after `value_items = ....`)

You need use `element_to_be_clickable` before your 1st line `value_items = ....`

Comment: This implies that elements can't be found until they are clickable, which doesn't sound correct to me...

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**:

```
def element_to_be_clickable(mark):
    """
    An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that
    you can click it.

    element is either a locator (text) or an WebElement
    """

    # renamed argument to 'mark', to indicate that both locator
    # and WebElement args are valid
    def _predicate(driver):
        target = mark
        if not isinstance(target, WebElement):  # if given locator instead of WebElement
                target = driver.find_element(*target)  # grab element at locator
        target = visibility_of(target)(driver)
        if target and target.is_enabled():
            return target
        else:
            return False

    return _predicate
```

So irrespective of a *locator* or a WebElement you have to pass as a **`tuple`**.

---

### This usecase

Your effective line of code will be:

```
self.wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((value)))
```

Comment: I continue to get the same TypeError after updating to the value argument to a tuple.